# How to automatically eliminate little magnitude noise

Tags: pca, robust, anomaly-detection

I'm working on an outlier detection method using the principal component pursuit(https://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RobustPCA.pdf). The algorithm decomposes the data matrix D = L+S;
L being a low rank matrix  and S a sparse gross error matrix. Here, the main assumption is that D is a Low rank matrix that has been corrupted by gross errors. Unfortunately, this assumption is violated by real world data sets; they are in the best case approximately low rank. This induces the algorithm to produce many little magnitude non zero entries in the S matrix. In the figure, i plotted two rows of S, the red plot is the errors vector corresponding  to a row vector of the data matrix, that i randomly corrupted. The blue curve represents an error vector that corresponds to a normal data row vector. I would like to get a zero error vector instead of the vector represented by the blue curve. That is, i am trying to find a way to set a threshold automatically, in order to flatten the small errors to zeros.

[image: GROSS ERRORS VS SMALL ERRORS]

I would be really thankful if you could help me.